# Why isn't my editor recognizing my typedef struct? C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, structure, typedef

New question: I have to read in data from files into an array of structures, and I'm getting errors with my scanf function.  I'm really unsure of the details of scanning into structures.  This is what I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define runnum 500
#define charnum 20

typedef struct {
        unsigned long bibnum;
        char lastname[charnum];
        char fistname[charnum];
        int grade;
        char team[charnum];
        char state[charnum];
        int time1;
        float time2;
    } runner_t;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    FILE *ifile, *jfile;

    ifile = fopen("20121006.boys.txt", "r");
    jfile = fopen("20121006.girls.txt", "r");

    runner_t runarray[runnum]; 

    i = 0;

    while  (i < runnum)
        {
            scanf(ifile, "%ul", &runarray[i].bibnum);
            scanf(ifile, "%s", &runarray[i].lastname);
            scanf(ifile, "%s", &runarray[i].firstname);
            scanf(ifile, "%d", &runarray[i].grade);
            scanf(ifile, "%s", &runarray[i].team);
            scanf(ifile, "%s", &runarray[i].state);
            scanf(ifile, "%d", &runarray[i].time1);
            scanf(ifile, "%f", &runarray[i].time2);
        printf("%d %s %s %d %s %s %d:%f", runarray[i].bibnum, runarray[i].lastname, runarray[i].firstname, runarray[i].grade, runarray[i].team, runarray[i].state, runarray[i].time1, runarray[i].time2); 
        i++;
     }
```

Comment: And which editor is that?

Comment: textwrangler, it's the one my prof advised us to use

Comment: Have you tried compiling it? who cares about the color?

Comment: I did try compiling it and I get a lot of errors/warnings.  I didn't put up everything I have written because I really think the error is in this, but I also tried to scan in things from files into each member, then i get these errors:  
LA2.c:33:38: error: request for member ‘bibnum’ in something not a structure or union
LA2.c:33:4: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘scanf’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/stdio.h:452:12: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’

and more of the same thing

Comment: Well, then it would depend on the code that tries to use this struct. May be a missing header inclusion. Show us the actual problem and not just the perfectly valid struct definition.

Comment: Type names ending in `_t` are reserved. Maybe your editor knows this? `did try compiling it and I get a lot of errors/warnings` **which** errors?

Comment: Sorry, this was where I tried to use it:
     while  (i < runnum)
      {
           scanf(ifile, "%ul", (&runarray[i]).bibnum);
       scanf(ifile, "%s", (&runarray[i]).lastname);
       scanf(ifile, "%s", (&runarray[i]).firstname);
       scanf(ifile, "%d", &runarray[i].grade);
       scanf(ifile, "%s", &runarray[i].team);
       scanf(ifile, "%s", &runarray[i].state);
       scanf(ifile, "%d", &runarray[i].time1);
       scanf(ifile, "%f", &runarray[i].time2);

Comment: @wildplasser I believe that (type names ending `_t` reserved) is a POSIX specification, not in standard C and does not apply to non-POSIX code. Still perhaps worth following, but an editor caring about that seems unlikely...

Comment: I changed the main question to include what @storyteller said, the whole question would be too long to put here though

Comment: You want `fscanf()`, not `scanf()`

Comment: oh my god I am so stupid I'm so sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: @Ali Since you haven't yet accepted any answer, and issue is solved: Please accept the one answer that was most helpful to you (the tick mark at the upper left corner of each answer), and consider upvoting (not sure if you need some more reputation points for that) any answers you also found helpful.

Comment: fwiw, the cutoff for upvoting appears to be 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

The editor problem is purely cosmetic. You can try this instead:

```
typedef struct runner_t {
    // ...
} runner_t;
```

Note though that the `_t` suffix is reserved on POSIX systems (like Mac OS X and Linux). It's better to either use `_type` instead, or no suffix at all.

Your problems though (the compilation errors) lie elswhere. First, you're using `scanf()` instead of `fscanf()`. `scanf()` always reads from the `stdin` stream and has no `FILE*` argument (so the compiler sees it as an error when you try to pass a `FILE*` as the first argument, since it always expects a `const char*` instead.) To read from your own file streams, you need to use `fscanf()`, which does take a `FILE*` argument. E.g.:

```
fscanf(ifile, "%lu", &runarray[i].bibnum);
```

Note: it's `%lu`, not `%ul`.)

Also note that when you read in the strings, you're passing pointers to them even though they're already pointers:

```
fscanf(ifile, "%s", &runarray[i].lastname);
```

Since `runner_t.lastname` is already a pointer, just pass it as-is:

```
fscanf(ifile, "%s", runarray[i].lastname);
```

Furthermore, you misspelled `runner_t.firstname` in the struct declaration. You named it `fistname`. Change that too.

Finally, in your `printf()`, you use `%d` as the format specifier to print `bignum`. Since it's an `unsigned long`, you need to use `%lu`.

Comment: I tried this and tried to compile it and get the same errors as I did before

Comment: @Ali The error has nothing to do with this. The declaration is correct. The error must have something to do with another part of your code.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, this is the place I tried to use it: 
 while  (i < runnum)
  {
   scanf(ifile, "%ul", (&runarray[i]).bibnum);
   scanf(ifile, "%s", (&runarray[i]).lastname);
   scanf(ifile, "%s", (&runarray[i]).firstname);
   scanf(ifile, "%d", &runarray[i].grade);
   scanf(ifile, "%s", &runarray[i].team);
   scanf(ifile, "%s", &runarray[i].state);
   scanf(ifile, "%d", &runarray[i].time1);
   scanf(ifile, "%f", &runarray[i].time2);

Comment: @Ali You're problem is that you're using `scanf()`. You need `fscanf()` to read from files.

Answer (score 0):

Your struct code is fine, see [this](http://ideone.com/pCPOXN) if you don't believe it otherwise. That ideone.com snippet adds just this main function, and works fine:

```
int main(void) {
  runner_t foo;
  printf ("sizeof foo is %zu\n", sizeof foo);
  return 0;
}
```

See http://sscce.org for good advice on how to avoid getting downvotes for badly asked question...

---

After edit: use `fscanf`, because `scanf` does not take `FILE*` as first argument (check documentation for both). Always check return value of any `scanf` family
function. Also check return value of `fopen` for errors.

Additionally, do not use `&` when passing array for `fscanf` `%s`. Name of array means address of array, and taking `&` of that makes no sense, and is not allowed. So for example: `fscanf(ifile, "%s", runarray[i].state);`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define RUNNUM 500
#define CHARNUM 20

typedef struct {
        unsigned long bibnum;
        char lastname[CHARNUM];
        char firstname[CHARNUM];
        int grade;
        char team[CHARNUM];
        char state[CHARNUM];
        int time1;
        float time2;
    } runner_t;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    FILE *ifile, *jfile;

    ifile = fopen("20121006.boys.txt", "r");
    jfile = fopen("20121006.girls.txt", "r");

    runner_t runarray[RUNNUM];

    for (i=0; i < RUNNUM; i++)
        {
            fscanf(ifile, "%lu", &runarray[i].bibnum);
            fscanf(ifile, "%s", runarray[i].lastname);
            fscanf(ifile, "%s", runarray[i].firstname);
            fscanf(ifile, "%d", &runarray[i].grade);
            fscanf(ifile, "%s", runarray[i].team);
            fscanf(ifile, "%s", runarray[i].state);
            fscanf(ifile, "%d", &runarray[i].time1);
            fscanf(ifile, "%f", &runarray[i].time2);
        printf("%lu %s %s %d %s %s %d:%f"
        , runarray[i].bibnum
        , runarray[i].lastname, runarray[i].firstname
        , runarray[i].grade, runarray[i].team
        , runarray[i].state
        , runarray[i].time1, runarray[i].time2);

     }
return 0;
}
```

Compiles here.